# Timestamp coming out as string when pulled from cloud firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I have pulled out a timestamp piece of data into an html data- attribute.

I then want to use this to populate a date form field that will be on a modal popup.

However when trying to use `toDate()` I am getting the error

`Uncaught TypeError: moderationDate.toDate is not a function`

To test I have used alerts to check the value and the type of data on the variable `moderationDate`. I can see that the data is being stored as a string in the html data attribute

```
<td data-moderateModerationDate="'+student.UnitGrades.IT6.Moderate.ModerationDate+'" >table data item</td> \

let moderationDate = $(this).attr("data-moderateModerationDate");

alert(moderationDate);
alert(typeof moderationDate);
```

- Alert 1 outputs - `Timestamp(seconds=0, nanoseconds=0)`
- Alert 2 outputs - `string`

Can anyone tell me why this is coming out as a string datatype and not as the raw timestamp?

Comment: $(this).attr("data-moderateModerationDate"); is a string and not a timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HTML data attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_data-.asp) can only store strings, so you can't expect to put anything into it and expect to get exactly that thing back.  The browser is converting it to a string when you store it, as you are adding it using string concatenation.  I'd suggest trying to find another way to store this value.